# Cannot use group with has_many through in Rails 5

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, has-many-through

I have the following associations:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :people_schools
    has_many :schools, through: :people_schools
end

class PeopleSchool < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :student
    belongs_to :school
end

class School < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :people_schools
    has_many :students, through: :people_schools
end
```

I am trying to get a list of students organized by their school.  I have tried the following:

```
Student.joins(:schools).all.group('schools.name')
```

but I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "students.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can a student be a student of many schools (`has_many :schools`) or should is he always a student of just one (`has_one :school`)? Or even `belongs_to :school` without the join table?

Answer (score 2):

When the association fires, it will generate a SQL query like

```
SELECT students.id, students. ...
FROM students
JOIN schools
ON ...
GROUP BY schools.name
```

In sql when grouping, a projection (SELECT) can only include columns that are grouped by or aggregations (e.g. `MAX`, `MIN`) of columns (regardless of whether they are grouped by). Therefore adding something like the following would turn it into a valid sql:

```
# column that is grouped by
Student.joins(:schools).group('schools.name').select('schools.name')
# aggregate function
Student.joins(:schools).group('schools.name').select('schools.name, COUNT(students.id)')
```

But how you want to fix it in your case depends on what you want to get out of the query.

**In answer to the comment**

Assuming a student is only member of a single school, which requires changing the association to a `belongs_to :school` (without the join table) or a `has_one :school` (with join table).

```
Student.includes(:school).group_by(&:school)
```

This will issue an SQL statement to get all students and their school (eager loaded for optimization). Only after the models (Student, School) are instantiated ruby objects, is the `group_by` method evaluated, which will return a Hash where the school is the key referencing an Array of students.

Comment: There are 12 schools.  I am trying to get an array of 12 arrays.  In each of those 12 arrays are each schools students.  I have used group_by to do this without has_many through before.