# How to group with has_many through in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have the following associations:

```
class Certificate < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :certificates_users
  has_many :users, :through => :certificates_users
end

class CertificatesUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :certificate
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :certificates_users, :dependent => :delete_all
  has_many :certificates, :through => :certificates_users
end
```

I am trying to get a list of Certificates and then group it by the user. Basically, list out all users and show a sublist of their certificates under them. Here's how the [UI looks like](https://codepen.io/mayordwells/pen/ZMoyGj) Just click on 'Mayor' on the table.

Here's the structure of the `CertificatesUser` table

```
=> CertificatesUser(certificate_id: integer, user_id: integer, expiry_date: date, certificate_number: string, renewal_date: date, ispublic: integer)
```

Following this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46572661/5012862), I was able to produce these possible solutions,

```
Certificate.joins(:users).group('users.id').select('users.id')

User.joins(:certificates).group('certificates.id').select('certificates.id, certificates.name')
```

The problem here is that most of the fields I need are on the `certificates_users` not on the `certificates` table.

This is another attempt at trying to get that to work, but did not work - `CertificatesUser.group(:user_id).select('user.id')`

What are other possible solutions to this?

Desired Output

[image]

Comment: I can help but you need to tell what the final column the query should fetch.. :) Right now I am confused

Comment: Thanks, @ArupRakshit for your response. I've attached the images of the desired output.
User's name and email from the user's table. OR we can access it through the user method on the join table. 
The same way we can access the Certificate name in the first column through the certificate method in the join table.

Comment: Ok, I'll add an answer if it remains unanswered.. :)

Comment: Alright. @ArupRakshit I'll be waiting, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by changing my approach and doing it the simplest way possible.

In the controller, I have this

```
@users_and_certificates = CertificatesUser.all.each_with_object({}) { |item, hash| hash[item.user_id] = item }
```

And then in the template, I query like this:

```
.card-body.table-responsive
  %table.table.table-hover.table-valign-middle
    %thead
      %tr
        %th Name
        %th E-mail
    %tbody
      - @users_and_certificates.each do |user_id, certificate_object|
         %tr{"data-target" => "#certificate_#{certificate_object.certificate_id}", "data-toggle" => "collapse"}
           - user = User.find(user_id)
           %td
             = user.full_name
           %td
             = user.email
         %tr
           %td.card-body.table-responsive.collapse{'id' => "certificate_#{certificate_object.certificate_id}"}
             %table.table.table-hover.table-valign-middle
               %thead
                 %tr
                   %th Certificate
                   %th Certificate No.
                   %th Expiry Date
                   %th Certificate
               %tbody
                 %tr
                   - certificate = Certificate.find(certificate_object.certificate_id)
                   %td
                     = certificate.name
                   %td
                     = certificate_object.certificate_number
                   %td
                     = certificate_object.expiry_date
                   %td Show
```

This works perfectly well for now. 
If anyone has a better approach, please don't hesitate to leave a comment or post an answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you can do

```
@users = User.includes(certificates_users: [:certificate])
```

then you can loop through them

```
@users.each do |u|
  u.certificates_users.each do |cu|
   cu.certificate_number
   cu.certificate.some_column
   ...
  end
end
```

to only get users with certificates

```
@users = User.includes(certificates_users: [:certificate]).where("certificates_users.user_id = users.id")
```

Comment: Thanks, @pavittar for your time. 
This command - `User.includes(certificates_users: [:certificate]` returned all users in the system, that's not the desired solution at all.
Btw did you check the link to the UI that I shared?

Comment: I don't see the problem with Pavattar's solution.  You want the certificates for all users, you just want to wrap the certificates for each user in a `div` with a unique id.  So `<% @users.each do |u| %>;<div id='certificates<%=u.id'>; <% u.certificates_users.each do |cu|%>;<%= u.certificate_number %>; <% end %>;</div>;<% end %>`

Comment: @mayorsanmayor if you don't want all the users apply some sort of offset and limit.

Answer (score 0):

Based on relation define in your models, below should work:

```
CertificatesUser.joins(:user, :certificate)        
    .select('user_id, users.name, users.email, certificates.name')
    .group_by(&:user_id)
```

You use `.group_by(&:user_id)` to group the fetched data based on user_id in array of json like below:

Sample of result:

```
[1, [{ user_id: 1, certificate_id: 29, ....},{ user_id: 1, certificate_id: 22, ....}] ,
2, [{ user_id: 2, certificate_id: 34, ....},{ user_id: 2, certificate_id: 56, ....}] ,
3, [{ user_id: 3, certificate_id: 29, ....},{ user_id: 3, certificate_id: 12, ....}] ]
```

**NB:**
You can add fields from **users** or **certificates** as you like but make sure you use them in *plural* and not in the *singular*.

Comment: Thanks @Shiko for your solution. But this did not work. Here's the error I got:

`ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError (Can't join 'CertificatesUser' to association named 'certificates'; perhaps you misspelled it?)`

Comment: Then I tried this - `Certificate.joins(:users).select('user_id, users.first_name, users.email, certificates.name').group(:user_id).group_by(&:user_id)`

And got this error. 
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "users.first_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function)`

Comment: @mayorsanmayor sorry my bad, no need for group() at db side, check the updated answer

Comment: Thanks, @Shiko, I changed my approach entirely. I really appreciate you taking your time to think about the question and post an answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is kind of side note but the naming does not make sense at all - `UserCertificate` would make much more sense.

Comment: Thanks, @max I found a better solution. Check my answer below.

Comment: @max correct, it will be meaningful if **UserCertificate**.